# Why base class method is being called inside inherited?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.2

In `self.inherited` method of base class, subclass is passed, calling subclass's `name` method instead calls base class method. Though same thing works If same method is called on same class elsewhere

```
class A
 def self.name 
  "a"
 end

 def self.inherited(subclass)
  puts B.hash
  puts B.name
 end
end

class B < A
 def self.name 
  "b"
 end
end

puts B.hash
puts B.name
```

output:

```
1428955046062147697
a
1428955046062147697
b
```

Comment: Does `inherited` kick in before or after the subclass has been created?

Comment: Fun fact: the built-in [`name`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-name) method would return `"B"` in either case (because constant assignment happens before the callback when using the `class` keyword).

Comment: Add the line `puts "cat"` right after `class B < A` and see when it's displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No magic here.

When you declare `B` the things happen in the following order (roughly speaking):

1. `B` (an instance of `Class`) is created (which inherits everything from `A`). At this moment it doesn't have anything specific.
2. `A.inherited` hook is invoked.
3. `B` class is opened and processed. Only at this point, it gets its own properties and methods (except the ones that could be created inside the hook).

So, when (2) happens the only `name` that is available for `B` is the one defined in `A`.

This is very easy to check using the following code:

```
class A
  def self.name 
    "a"
  end

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    puts "B own methods, point 1: #{subclass.methods(false).join(', ')}"
  end
end

class B < A
  puts "B own methods, point 2: #{self.methods(false).join(', ')}"

  def self.name 
    "b"
  end

  puts "B own methods, point 3: #{self.methods(false).join(', ')}"
end

# B own methods, point 1: 
# B own methods, point 2: 
# B own methods, point 3: name
```

Everything is clear now, right?

Comment: there seems to be a need for post_inherited method, otherwise if I have to process  class by some user defined values it becomes cumbersome.

Comment: What do you want to do with imaginary `post_inherited` that cannot be done via class (re)opening and common Ruby idioms?

Comment: @AnuragUniyal, that would require a determination of when the construction of the inherited class is completed, which may be problematic. Moreover, considering that while the child is being constructed it could modify the parent or create a sibling. I'm not sure what the implications of such actions might be for a `post_inherited` method. I expect the main reason for `inherited` is build a list of instances.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov it can be done with inherited but not elegant, e.g. how do you make a hash of `{name => subclass}`

Comment: @AnuragUniyal you can build just a list of descendants using `inherited` and then build the hash on demand... Or you can use the same approach as Rais does for the `.descendants` method which doesn't use hooks at all (ObjectSpace is used instead)